# How do I get all class properties that accomplish a requisit established in its attribute value?

Tags: c#, reflection, properties, filter, attributes

To make it clear, little example:

```
public class Book
{
    [MyAttrib(isListed = true)]
    public string Name;

    [MyAttrib(isListed = false)]
    public DateTime ReleaseDate;

    [MyAttrib(isListed = true)]
    public int PagesNumber;

    [MyAttrib(isListed = false)]
    public float Price;
}
```

The question is: how do I get only properties where the bool parameter `isListed` is set `true` on `MyAttrib`?

This is what I got:

```
PropertyInfo[] myProps = myBookInstance.
                         GetType().
                         GetProperties().
                         Where(x => (x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttrib), false).Length > 0)).ToArray();
```

`myProps` got all properties from `Book`, but now, I can't figure out how to exclude them, when its `isListed` parameter returns false.

```
foreach (PropertyInfo prop in myProps)
{
    object[] attribs = myProps.GetCustomAttributes(false);

    foreach (object att in attribs)
    {
        MyAttrib myAtt = att as MyAttrib;

        if (myAtt != null)
        {
            if (myAtt.isListed.Equals(false))
            {
                // if is true, should I add this property to another PropertyInfo[]?
                // is there any way to filter?
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be very apreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using Linq's query syntax would be a bit easier.

```
var propList = 
    from prop in myBookInstance.GetType()
                               .GetProperties()
    let attrib = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttrib), false)
                     .Cast<MyAttrib>()
                     .FirstOrDefault()
    where attrib != null && attrib.isListed
    select prop;
```